# ionic 4 sub paths not loading when running ionic serve

Tags: ionic-framework, serve

I had an ionic 4 beta project of `--type=angular` that was loading at any path without issue.

Periodically, i have been updating my packages by running an `npm update` and am currently at:

```
"@ionic/angular": "^4.0.2"
```

as well as updated installs for the ionic cli, and am currently at:

```
CLI 4.10.3
```

I am not sure when this app loading issue started, but i suspect it was after running the last `npm update` or update install of the cli.

When running `ionic serve` my application loads correctly, and i am able to navigate to all sub paths without any issues.

However, when:

• refreshing the browser while viewing a sub path

• attempting to enter a url with a sub path

• live reloading while viewing a sub path

the app attempts to load all `js` files relative to the sub path and fails to run like so:

```
http://localhost:8100/page/sub/path
```

fails to load because the app attempts to load `runtime.js` here:

```
http://localhost:8100/page/sub/path/runtime.js
```

my base href is currently set to `./`

When i inspect the html source, the script tags are formatted as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="runtime.js"></script>
```

If i attempt to load a page directly at the root, the application loads ok without issue like so:

`http://localhost:8100` loads OK

`http://localhost:8100/page` loads OK

So again to recap, the app only fails to load the js assets at a sub path.

Any idea where to begin troubleshooting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone running into this same problem, i have the answer.

I am not sure when or why, but my base href was set incorrectly and this was the problem.

I changed my base href from `./` to `/` and this solved my problem.